# Android "open with..." gives different URLS (intent-filter)

Tags: android, pdf, android-intent

I want my app to be able to open external pdfs, so implemented this intent-filter which allows me to open my app when selecting a PDF.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/pdf" />
        </intent-filter>
```

On some devices the data url is something like:

```
content://downloads/all_downloads/4860
```

which i can open with this piece of code:

```
Cursor returnCursor = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(returnUri, null, null, null, null);
```

On other devices like One plus One (can't really figure out what the difference is in Android version) the intent received this URL:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/pdf-test.pdf
```

I can not open this URL because i probably have no access to it. Anyone knows what i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it was easy after all. Had to request permissions to read/write external storage so i could handle the file url.